# Fastest possible MYSQL SELECT query with JOINS (join itself)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, select, indices

i am having some trouble with indices and the performance of my query.
I am currently doing as following:

```
SELECT 
    images.imageId, 
    path, 
    fileName, 
    alt, 
    description, 
    width, 
    height 
FROM 
    images 
LEFT JOIN imagesEn ON images.imageId=imagesEn.imageId 

WHERE 

images.adId = ?

AND images.imageStatus = 1 
AND images.isPreview = 1 
AND (images.isBanner = 0 OR images.isBanner IS NULL) 

ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;';
```

This gives me the image i want. But i am using responsive picture elements, there are smaller versions of the image.
My limited sql-knowledge forced me to use another query then like so:

```
SELECT 
    images.imageId, 
    relativePathToImageFromImgFolder, 
    fileName, 
    altAttribute, 
    description, 
    width, 
    height 
FROM 
    images 
LEFT JOIN imagesEn ON images.imageId=imagesEn.imageId 

WHERE 

images.adId = ? 

AND images.imageStatus = 1 
AND images.isPreview = 0 
AND images.isSmallerVersionOf = ?

ORDER by width DESC
```

Then i am ending up with two queries and two arrays which gives me the main image plus all the smaller versions of the image to create my picture element.
The join is needed because i have several languages (imagesEn, imagesDe, imagesFr, etc.) which joins the filename, attributes in the given language.
I have just set single-column indices, multi-column indices are new to me i have heard from the the first time today :D.
I am showing something like producte on a product page and my page-generation time is about 0.3 seconds (uncashed). All my other pages have 0.0x second which is my goal for that page, too.
Plus i am doing this query inside a loop

```
$query = 'SELECT name, id, url, whatever from products where productColor = "blue";';
foreach($arr as $r)
{
    $str .= '<div>';
            $str .= $r['name'] . ' ' . $r['whatever'];
            $str .= self::createPictureElementFromId($r['id']);  //this calls the above queries to create the picture element with its main image and the child images (smaller versions for smaller screens)
    $str .= '</div>';
}

return $str;
```

Hope the description is precise enough ;).
Thanks in advance

Comment: The isSmallerVersionOf points to the images.imageId of the first query ? All the images *have* smaller version?

Comment: Yes it does!
All images have smaller versions, depending on their uploaded sizes, i am not upscaling anything. So there might be some rare cases without smaller versions of them, but this is been handled by my function (if empty array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. It joins two times the images table (one for the normal image and the second for the smaller version if it exists), and two times the ImageEn table which should have the translation of the description and other things.

If you're only looking for one image your DB time won't be so much better.

The alias of the tables in the select fields should be wrong, because I don't know where it's each field. The description should be on imagesEn and imagesEn2

This only gets one smaller version of the image. If you have lots of smaller images you can join three times the images table, but IMHO it should be cleaner the way you're doing it at the moment in your code with two selects.

```
SELECT 
    i.imageId, 
    i.path, 
    i.fileName, 
    i.alt, 
    i.description, 
    i.width, 
    i.height,
    i2.relativePathToImageFromImgFolder, 
    i2.fileName, 
    i2.altAttribute, 
    i2.description, 
    i2.width, 
    i2.height

FROM 
    images as i
LEFT JOIN imagesEn as iEn ON i.imageId=iEn.imageId 
LEFT JOIN images as i2 on ((i2.isSmallerVersionOf = i.imageID) AND (i2.imageStatus = 1)  AND (i2.isPreview = 0))
LEFT JOIN imagesEn2 as IEn2 ON i2.imageId = iEn2.imageId

WHERE 

i2.adId = ?

AND i.imageStatus = 1 
AND i.isPreview = 1 
AND (i.isBanner = 0 OR i.isBanner IS NULL) 

ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i have one two fifteen smaller versions or even more, it depends on the incoming resolution. I am supporting from 4k to mobile. I assume joining that much tables would make it even slower. So caching or a temporary table might be my way to go then?

Comment: IMHO in a similar system I have I create automatically all the thumbnails sizes I need, in your case it should be a bigger amount. If you don't need the same amount of images for all the images you can set a image profile 1=1 image, 2=2 images (800x600, 640x480), 3=3 images 2 + 1024, .... And all the image files should have a number specifying the size image1-1.jpg, image1-2.jpg, ... With that system you only need one row in the database for each image, because the description should be the same for all the images, alt-atribute and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`i.isBanner = 0 OR i.isBanner IS NULL` -- pick one.  This will let you get rid of `OR`, which is a performance killer.

Then have `INDEX(adId, imageStatus, isPreview, isBanner)` (in any order).  This should allow the filtering to run faster.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, since I am having to guess at some of your datatypes, etc.

To do the `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`, it is inefficient to haul around all the columns, only to pick one of them.  So, instead do this:

```
SELECT i.imageId, i.path, ...
    FROM ( SELECT imageId FROM images WHERE ...
               ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ) AS x
    JOIN images i  USING(imageId)
```

But then you need `INDEX(adId, imageStatus, isPreview, isBanner, imageId)` so that the inner query can run entirely in the index.

"Smaller version" -- Have the flag say "this is a small image" and include it in the `WHERE` and the `INDEX`.

Language URL -- Add another `JOIN` to the above to get the language-specific URL, which should be in *another table*.  That table should have `PRIMARY KEY(imageId, lang)`.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look into this as soon as possible ;).